# Concatenate cells based on criteria

Tags: excel

So, I am trying to find the most effective way to concatenate some values to see what are the missing assignments that my students need to turn in. I have a table similar like this (the dates represent when the delivered the homework):

| ID | Name | Homework 1 | Homework 2 | Homework 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 |
| 2 | Peter | 08/07/21 | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 |
| 3 | Leslie | 08/07/21 | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 |
| 4 | Karla |  | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 |
| 5 | Susy |  |  |  |
| 6 | Ed | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 |

My desired output will be another column called "Missing Assignments" with the name/number of the missing homework like this:

| ID | Name | Homework 1 | Homework 2 | Homework 3 | Missing assignments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 |  |
| 2 | Peter | 08/07/21 | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 |  |
| 3 | Leslie | 08/07/21 | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 |  |
| 4 | Karla |  | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 | Homework 1 |
| 5 | Susy |  |  |  | Homework 1, Homework 2, Homework 3, |
| 6 | Ed | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 | 09/07/21 |  |

The formula that I was thinking to use was

```
=IF([@[Homework 1]]<>"","","Homework 1")
```

And then apply the same logic for all the other assignments.. But I am sure that should be a better way of doing it. Because for this example it "works" since I have only 3 columns with the assignments, but how could I achieve it if I had 50 assignments instead of just 3? It seems kind of odd having to do it using the formula that I am using right now.

Another option could be using TEXTJOIN

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF([@[Homework 1]]<>"","","Homework 1"), IF([@[Homework 2]]<>"","","Homework 2"), IF([@[Homework 3]]<>"","","Homework 3"),
```

However, I am still going to need to work with multiple IF´s.

What do you suggest me?

Comment: what version do you have?  If you have an Excel with TEXTJOIN() it is possible, otherwise you are stuck with concatenating multiple `IF`s, one for each column.

Comment: My version supports TEXTJOIN (). Could you please share with me any material related to that?

Comment: =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF([@[Homework 1]]<>"","","Homework 1"), IF([@[Homework 2]]<>"","","Homework 2"), IF([@[Homework 3]]<>"","","Homework 3")) - I tried this formula with TEXTJOIN but I am facing the same problem (multiple IF´s). Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(Table1[@[Homework 1]:[Homework 3]]="",Table1[[#Headers],[Homework 1]:[Homework 3]],""))
```

Depending on your version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]